# How to retrive some jpeg image from Wikipedia page by API?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki-api

For my app I need to extract images from the Wikipedia API. But I am not getting the correct API to get the jpeg image from main Wikipedia pages. I have tried the Sandbox API, but not succeeded yet. At present I have the following API request, which is not showing images according to my expectation. Is there any API request that I should use to get an image from the Wikipedia main page.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&generator=images&iiurlwidth=400&generator=images&titles=Kiel
```

Comment: And what is your expectation?

Comment: In the response you have the url of all the images.

Comment: @MaxSem; I want to send request for query image. My expectation is that with this query I get some nice jpeg image from the page. because with my query I got the images which is not helpful so much.

Comment: @AleFranz: I want to get three images including the main image of wikipedia. As I am new handling this problem, Can you tell me how can I get some images like google overview in wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the pages from Wikipedia are associated with an Item in Wikidata. If there is **"main image"** for some wiki item it will be kept by [Image (P18) property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P18). This property you can access by using [MediaWiki API for Wikidata with wbgetentities action](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Paris
```

In this example, the article [Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris) (titles=Paris) in English Wikipedia (sites=enwiki) will returns Wikidata [Item (Q90)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q90) with its Image property. You can be more specific in request by using **&props=claims** to miss all unnecessary information like labels, descriptions, sitelinks etc. The result will include:

```
{
    "entities": {
        "Q90": {
            "claims": {
                "P18": [ {
                    "mainsnak": {
                        "datavalue": {
                            "value": "Paris - Eiffelturm und Marsfeld2.jpg",
                        },
                    },
                } ],
            }
        }
    },
}
```

where the value *"[Paris - Eiffelturm und Marsfeld2.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Paris_-_Eiffelturm_und_Marsfeld2.jpg)"* is the main image of the article.